# How would I cache paginated content in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am making a website that displays 20 records per page, up to an infinite amount of pages, and the page count will change as users upload content. I'm looking for a way to cache these pages for X amount of time (say an hour or two) to increase load times and reduce the load on my database. How would I go about caching paginated content?

My one and only theory would be to pull a large subset from the DB (say 1000) rows and serialize & cache the array, then use that subset for the first pages until I run out, and when the users hit the end of it, i'll just pull more from the DB and deal with the risk of an offset or duplicate data items.

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: It seems appropriate to use [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php) for your datastore.

Comment: If you want to avoid new data bumping your pagenation around, would it be possible to use a WHERE clause with a "records older than <date>" in your system from the initial search for subsequent pages and make use of the LIMIT statement or is having a cache ultimately required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only problem I see - it is infinite amount of pages. This solution may help you:

1) you need an unique index for columns you will order by your data when displaying it. This index must be in the same order as you will order your data.

2) You dont need to cache all dataset - just cache first index value for each 100'th (or 100th, or 10th) page

3) forget about cache liferime - just do invalidation manually when content changes

For example you want to display questions:

```
CREATE TABLE `qeustions` (
  `id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `question` TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UN_questions_created` (`created_at` DESC, `id`) 
  /* we just add `id` to provide uniqueness */
) ENGINE = InnoDB CHARACTER SET latin1;
```

When you need to display N-th page, look at cache for the clothest page you store. For example you want to display 120th page, so looak at the 100th page in cache. If you dont find it - simply redirect user to 100th page, run select:

```
SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 2000, 20;
```

And then put to cache key (created_at, id) for 100th page. Second time you need to display 120th page, just bring from cache key for 100th page and run query like that:

```
SELECT * FROM questions 
WHERE created_at <= [created_at_from_cache] AND id >= [id_from_cache]
LIMIT 400, 20
```

So you will avoid large numbers from LIMIT.

It is only workaround - it is not an excellent solution, but I hope this workaround helps you.

Comment: I decided to implement something similar to what you suggest and it works beautifully, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

That may be not a good idea to store everything in cache. But, if you are understand what are you doing, take a look at [MySQL`s MEMORY tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/memory-storage-engine.html), [memcache](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php), [redis](http://redis.io/). There are a lot of key-value storages.